# Windows OpenJDK doesn't match with Linux OpenJDK

Tags: linux, java

I develop on Windows deploy on linux. I couldn't find the same version OpenJdk of windows and linux. So I installed `openjdk_1.7.0_u80-unofficial` for windows and `openjdk-1.7.0.71.x86_64` for linux. Will there be a problem? Or please suggest a better way to do it.

Linux OS: RedHat 6.6

Answer (score -1):

Probably not. Unless there are some bug that's been fixed in one version but not the other or new bugs have been introduced, you're likely not going to feel any effects; and even that's the case, you're unlikely to hit any of those bugs anyway.